# Cross-application auto testing for complex business cases

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests

I have few web application designed for different users, with different databases. These application can work on their own, but there are some complex scenarios where applications communicate.
Let's say we have 3 applications for 3 groups of users.

We have a business process where user from group 1 create something (let's call it project) in application 1, then user 2 can see this project also in application 2.

He/she can add something to this project with application 2. Then there is user 3 that works only with application 3 where you can verify that project has been created and everything is in place, he can see it in application 3 and make some more changes.

I would like to somehow automate this end-to-end test and not really sure what approach should I have here. I can test each application separately (API tests, some UI tests with selenium/playwright etc.) but when it comes to more complex 'cross-application' scenario I am a bit lost.
Are there any good practices/standards/tools to do this?

Comment: You will need to share your code to allow us to assist

Comment: What code? The question is not about the code, rather about approach. There are few web applications that can be a part of one, big business scenario. What are the options when it come to AT?

Comment: Ive added an answer around some generalities and thoughts which hopefully helps

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a wide ranging, "how long is a piece of string" type questions, but I am happy to give some suggestions around how I would handle this.

Firstly, comes the question of test scope. If you are dealing with testing inside project boundaries, more modular testing such as your Unit, Integration and smaller functional tests is the key, with some E2E depending on your goals. This is all standard stuff when it comes to testing.

For the cross boundary testing however, this is where I tend to use E2E tests for most of the coverage, as this crosses the boundary of one and into another. For me, ill use PlayWright as my tool for talks sake, but fill that with Selenium or any other you are comfortable with.

When doing this form of testing, I like to scope it to user-centric tests, where each user will have tests for their respective part, i.e. user1 can create x and validate its done correctly etc.

If you wish to create longer full flow tests across multiple users, this is fine too. With Playwright, you can create multiple isolated contexts and authenticate this for your various users. So in your case, context1 would perform user1's actions, and then context2 is created and user2 does their action, and so on.

https://playwright.dev/docs/browser-contexts

Though, as you dont have a tool nor language mentioned, I wont bore you with playwright JS mockups.

To summarise, there really are many ways to go about this, but the goal you have is very do-able and common. If you decide on a tool or have specific implementation questions, be sure to raise and I can always help.